# momentJS-timezone always displays UTC time

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I am having trouble getting time(HH:mm) from different timezone.
Tried it with the moment-timezone doc and searched stackoverflow.

I even found a working jquery fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/uq99udc9/4/

(actually wanted to not use jquery, but gave it a try)
Literally copy/pasted the fiddle in my project and in an empty JS file. But "Thailand date time" and "America date time" always show "moment.js utc local timezone UTC". So right now it displays 07:00pm (UTC time at the moment) on both Thailand AND America...

What am I doing wrong?

Of course tried the docs example as well

```
var a = moment.tz("2013-11-18 11:55", "America/Toronto");
var b = moment.tz("May 12th 2014 8PM", "MMM Do YYYY hA", "America/Toronto");
var c = moment.tz(1403454068850, "America/Toronto");
a.format(); // 2013-11-18T11:55:00-05:00
b.format(); // 2014-05-12T20:00:00-04:00
c.format(); // 2014-06-22T12:21:08-04:00
```

I am just not getting it, I think. What time/date would you pass in the first argument before "America/Toronto" for instance?

Comment: Where is your code? The code you pasted is just from the Moment docs.

Comment: Are you loading the moment timezone library?

Comment: The code I am running in my project is a copy/past of the fiddle-link above.
Yes, Ive included the timezone libary. simple .utc() for instance works.

Comment: Check that you had imported `moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js`, `utc ()` is just part of moment.js core (without timezone).

Comment: Thanks! Just imported, but still not working. Still get UTC three times.
I am including in that order:
moment.js
moment-timezone.js
moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.js

Any other leads or ideas? Thank you!

Comment: I think i just dont get it... tried it that way as well:  currentTime = moment.tz("America/Los_Angeles").format("HH:mm");
document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML = currentTime;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe someone can give me a working example? Because I am just not getting along with the docs, when even the jsfiddle didnt work.

UPDATE: I worked it out!!
The problem was, that i was importing/including moment.js, moment-timezone.js, moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.js.

But in fact: I only have to import moment,js and moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.js... As soon as I deleted moment-timezone.js, everything was working fine.
Cheers!